# Force refresh of an affix in Vue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am using a bootstrap affix within a Vue JS page. When I first navigate to the route containing the affix (the affix visibility is controlled via `v-if`), it works perfectly with scrolling. However, when I navigate *away* from that route and then *back* again, the affix is broken: it is stuck at the top of the page and doesn't scroll.

I have found online that, were I using jquery, I could call `$('#affix').affix('checkPosition')` to force the affix to reposition (but I don't have access to jquery).

I suspect the issue is that Vue is creating the affix on the first load, and then caches the same DOM object to be used later. But when it is re-inserted into the page, bootstrap is no longer aware of it and the affixing behavior breaks.

At this point, I think I have a few options, any of which would solve this problem:

- Is there a smart way to call Jquery from within a Vue component? I'm not using Jquery anywhere else, so would rather not.
- Is there a way to force Bootstrap affixes to refresh?
- Is there a way to force Vue to not cache this component, creating a new one every load?
- Is there a better way of creating an affix with Vue?

Thanks!

Here is the Vue component of concern:

```
<template>
  <div id="funclist-affix" class="panel panel-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="155">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h4>Functions</h4>
      <div class="list-group function-list">
        <router-link v-for="(func,line) in functions" :key="line" :to="'#' + func.name" :class="['list-group-item', 'code', {uncovered: func.uncovered}]" :title="func.name">{{ func.name }}</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'functionList',
  data () {
    return {

    }
  },
  props: ['functions']
}
</script>

<style>
a {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#funclist-affix {
  max-height: calc(100% - 2 * 20px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for that.

```
<template>
  <!-- notice ref="myAffix" -->
  <div ref="myAffix" id="funclist-affix" class="panel panel-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="155">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</template>
```

And in your component script:

```
<script>    
export default {
  name: 'functionList',
  data () {
    return {

    }
  },
  props: ['functions'],
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.myAffix.affix('checkPosition')
  }
}
</script>
```

Edit: You can also use `vue-strap`, it has an affix component.

https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap

Comment: But since I'm in Vue, I don't have access to Jquery. i.e. `$` is not defined.

Comment: if you are using `npm`. then install jquery using `npm i jquery --save` then import jquery globally. `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')` before creating your Vue instance.

Comment: I'd hate to load jQuery just to run a single function. Is there no way to ask bootstrap to do the above?